# How do I add an extra "Add content"-link to the admin toolbar dropdown

Tags: 8, navigation

I am trying to add some improvement to the workflow of the webmasters. Right now they have to click "Content", and then click once more on the "Add content" button. Since I am working with the "Admin toolbar" module, I want to add a "/node/add" link below the "Content" link in a dropdown. But no success yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple. First, create a **your_module.links.menu.yml** file in your custom module and add the following:

```
your_module.admin:
  title: 'Add content'
  parent: system.admin_content
  url: internal:/node/add
```

Clear cache and you're done!